# Goat racing up a hill (C++ hiring take-home)

Tags: c++, interview-questions, c++20

This is an interview take-home challenge that has been translated to avoid compromising the company's question.

### Problem statement

You are a goat that needs to race up a hill. Designated waypoint rocks on the hill must each be visited in sequence or skipped and a score penalty incurred. For the goat to get its balance, it must pause ten seconds on each rock. Travel between rocks occurs on a straight line at two metres per second.

Coordinates and penalties per rock are all integral and exist in the open interval (0, 100). Rock designations are spatially unique. The start rock at (0, 0) and the finish rock at (100, 100) are implied and not included in input.

Minimise the total cost of the goat's chosen path, calculated as the sum of all time spent and all penalties incurred.

Input is specified on `stdin` as one or more races followed by a final `0`. Each race is specified by an integer `n` on one line - the number of rocks (excluding the start and finish) - followed by `n` lines, each an integer triple `x y p`, the coordinates of the rock and the penalty incurred if it is skipped.

Output on `stdout` is a single line per race, the path cost to three digits after the decimal.

### Test cases

Input (`sample_input_small.txt`):

```
1
50 50 20
3
30 30 90
60 60 80
10 90 100
3
30 30 90
60 60 80
10 90 10
0
```

Output (`sample_output_small.txt`):

```
90.711
156.858
110.711
```

### Implementation

I have a long-winded explainer that I might not paste here, but suffice to say that the implementation is amortised O(n). I used C++ because I need to catch up on best practices for versions 11+. The current compiler invocation looks like

```
 g++ -O3 -s -march=native -fomit-frame-pointer --std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

It's pretty fast - for the biggest well-formed input of 9801 rocks, it executes in less than 10ms.

### Review

Any feedback welcome, but I'm particularly interested in idiomatic use of modern C++ and associated data structures, and performance.

### Code

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <cassert>
#include <cmath>
#include <exception>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>


namespace {
    constexpr int
        delay = 10,
        speed = 2;
    constexpr double
        dist_min = 1,
        dist_max = 100*M_SQRT2,
        time_min = dist_min / speed,
        time_max = dist_max / speed;

    class Waypoint {
    public:
        const int x, y, penalty = 0;

        Waypoint(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) { }
        Waypoint(int x, int y, int penalty) : x(x), y(y), penalty(penalty) { }

        static Waypoint read(std::istream &in) {
            int x, y, penalty;
            in >> x >> y >> penalty;
            return Waypoint(x, y, penalty);
        }

        double time_to(const Waypoint &other) const {
            int dx = x - other.x, dy = y - other.y;
            double distance = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
            return distance / speed;
        }
    };


    class OptimisedWaypoint {
    public:
        const Waypoint &waypoint;
        const double best_cost = 0;
        const int penalty = 0;

        OptimisedWaypoint(const Waypoint &visited): waypoint(visited) { }

        OptimisedWaypoint(const Waypoint &visited, double best_cost, int penalty):
            waypoint(visited), best_cost(best_cost), penalty(penalty) { }

        double cost_for(const Waypoint &visited) const {
            double time = visited.time_to(waypoint);
            return time + best_cost - penalty + delay;
        }

        double invariant_cost() const {
            return best_cost - penalty;
        }

        bool operator<(const OptimisedWaypoint &other) const {
            return invariant_cost() < other.invariant_cost();
        }
    };


    void prune(std::multiset<OptimisedWaypoint> &opt_waypoints) {
        double to_exceed = opt_waypoints.cbegin()->invariant_cost() + time_max - time_min;

        for (auto w = opt_waypoints.crbegin(); w != opt_waypoints.crend(); w++) {
            if (w->invariant_cost() < to_exceed) {
                opt_waypoints.erase(w.base(), opt_waypoints.end());
                break;
            }
        }
    }


    double get_best_cost(
        const Waypoint &visited,
        const std::multiset<OptimisedWaypoint> &opt_waypoints
    ) {
        double best_cost = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

        for (const OptimisedWaypoint &skipto: opt_waypoints) {
            double cost = skipto.cost_for(visited);
            if (best_cost > cost) best_cost = cost;
        }

        return best_cost;
    }


    double solve(const std::vector<Waypoint> &waypoints) {
        std::multiset<OptimisedWaypoint> opt_waypoints;
        opt_waypoints.emplace(waypoints.back());
        const auto end = std::prev(waypoints.crend());

        int total_penalty = 0;

        for (auto visited = std::next(waypoints.crbegin());; visited++) {
            total_penalty += visited->penalty;
            double best_cost = get_best_cost(*visited, opt_waypoints);
            if (visited == end)
                return best_cost + total_penalty;

            opt_waypoints.emplace(*visited, best_cost, visited->penalty);

            prune(opt_waypoints);
        }
    }


    void process_streams(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {
        constexpr std::ios::iostate mask = std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit;
        in.exceptions(mask);
        out.exceptions(mask);

        for (;;) {
            int n;
            in >> n;
            if (n == 0) break;

            std::vector<Waypoint> waypoints;
            waypoints.reserve(n+2);
            waypoints.emplace_back(0, 0);
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
                waypoints.push_back(Waypoint::read(in));
            waypoints.emplace_back(100, 100);

            out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << solve(waypoints) << std::endl;
        }
    }


    void compare(std::istream &out_exp, std::istream &out_act) {
        for (;;) {
            std::string time_exp, time_act;
            if (!std::getline(out_exp, time_exp)) {
                if (out_exp.eof()) break;
                throw std::ios::failure("getline");
            }
            out_act >> time_act;
            std::cout << time_exp << " == " << time_act << std::endl;
            assert(time_exp == time_act);
        }
    }


    void test() {
        constexpr const char *cases[] = {"small", "medium", "large"};

        for (const char *const case_name: cases) {
            std::stringstream out_act;

            {
                std::ostringstream fnin;
                fnin << "sample_input_" << case_name << ".txt";
                std::ifstream in;
                in.open(fnin.str());
                process_streams(in, out_act);
            }

            std::ostringstream fnout;
            fnout << "sample_output_" << case_name << ".txt";
            std::ifstream out_exp;
            out_exp.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);
            out_exp.open(fnout.str());

            out_act.seekp(0);
            compare(out_exp, out_act);
        }
    }


    void main() {
        process_streams(std::cin, std::cout);
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    try {
        if (argc > 1 && std::string(argv[1]) == "-t")
            test();
        else main();
    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: (I don't get the testcase outputs - is a final 10 seconds pause to be included?)

Comment: Continued in [Goats up hills II: revenge of the goat](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/279684/goats-up-hills-ii-revenge-of-the-goat).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`M_SQRT2` is not part of the standard library
and does not exist on all conforming implementations.
The portable C++20 version is

```cpp
#include <numbers>

constexpr double dist_max = 100 * std::numbers::sqrt2;
```

Before C++20, you may consider supplying your own definition of the constant
since `std::sqrt` is not `constexpr`.

The spacing style `T& x` is much more common than `T &x` in C++.

I don't think it is useful to put everything (other than `main`)
in an anonymous namespace for a one-file script.

Since the conversion factor \$\sqrt{2}\$ is unavoidable,
you might as well store everything in `double` to save type conversions.

`const` data members are generally a mistake (outside rare use cases) —
usually, a `const` object is intended instead.
Also, it is more idiomatic to define simple data structures like `Waypoint` as aggregates:

```cpp
struct Waypoint {
    int x, y, penalty = 0;

    // no user-defined constructors
}
```

so that it can be constructed like `Waypoint { x, y, penalty }`.
The same goes for `OptimizedWaypoint`.

<s>Prefer [`std::hypot(dx, dy)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/hypot) over `std::sqrt(dx * dx, dy * dy)`.</s>.  As Reinderien pointed out in comments, the extra precision guaranteed by `hypot` may cause performance degradation.  If performance is the concern, we might consider creating a handmade even faster version if we don’t need the extra precision (since we are dealing with integers anyway).

Prefer `++w` over `w++` (especially) when `w` is an iterator,
unless you need the return value of `w++`.

In `prune`, I believe you are looking for [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multiset/lower_bound).
In that case, you probably need to refactor the code a bit, though.
(In fact, I feel that the whole `OptimizedWaypoint` design
should be replaced by something like `std::multimap<double, Waypoint>`.)

Similarly, in `get_best_cost`, use [`std::min_element`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/min_element).

The effect of `std::setprecision(3)` remains until the precision is changed again,
so you do not need to do it every time you print a number.

Instead of creating a default-initialized stream and then calling `open`,
simply pass the file as an argument when creating the stream.

Finally, `std::string(argv[1]) == "-t"`
can be simplified to `argv[1] == "-t"sv`
if you have `using namespace std::string_view_literals;`.

Comment: The reason for the anonymous namespace is that it acts as the C-equivalent static linkage - don't expose symbols you don't need to expose, and offer the optimiser an opportunity to do what it wants with function bounds. Would you suggest a different way to accomplish the same thing?

Comment: Is it really possible to use `min_element`? Note the function call instead of a collection.

Comment: The reason for separating `open` from construction is to set exception flags

Comment: Whereas `hypot` seems like a really nice function for this application, surprisingly it incurs a 20% performance hit

Comment: I suspect that's because `std::hypot()` takes great care to get the result right even in pathological cases (avoiding underflow and overflow).  We're not going to hit those cases here, but still pay the cost, unfortunately.  You could always define a `naive_hypot()` function, and perhaps even allow choice of which implementation to use.

Comment: Haven’t tried it myself, but adding `-ffast-math` to the compile parameters might lessen the hit from using `std::hypot()`.

Comment: @indi `-Ofast` (which includes `-ffast-math`) does not reduce the hit

Comment: Yup, looks like neither GCC nor Clang optimize `hypot()` yet. [Here’s the GCC bug for it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88474). Looks like it’s just not a priority.

Comment: @hanshenrik It can make a real difference for complex types.

Comment: @Reinderien (1) Static linkage does reduce the amount code emitted, but I don’t think it affects inlining and other optimizations (in the case of a simple one-file program).  (2) `std::min_element` can take a functor argument.  However, since we are using C++20, we can use `std::views::transform` even more easily.  (3) You can always call `exceptions` after opening the file.  (4) Good point - I will update the answer.

Comment: ```The spacing style T& x is much more common than T &x in C++.``` - well people should cut it out. It's easy to see what `T &x, y` means, but it's not easy to see what `T& x, y` means.. the & is tied to the first variable, thus it should be `T &x,y`  not `T& x,y`

Answer (score 8):

I prefer to keep the tests separate from the production code, rather than mixed together like this.  One reason is that when building a product, we don't need to link the tests into the shipping binary, for a large saving in footprint.

We have the `process_streams()` interface that accepts an input stream and an output stream; that should be the point where we can seamlessly drive from the production code or from the test framework, without having any test-specific functions in our implementation.

Tests are better if they include everything needed right there.  So instead of storing test data in separate files (which adds complexity to the test code), I would prefer to see those inputs and expected outputs right there as literals, and use string-streams to pass to `process_streams()`.

Also, I dislike the use of the name `main()` for a function in the anonymous namespace.  That's too similar to global `main()` for comfort.

Answer (score 4):

I think you can simplify the algorithm a little. Performance will stay roughly the same, but you gain readability.

- Use one struct instead of two.
- Don't write a constructor, use the default one and curly braces initialization.
- Use `double` for everything (because why not).
- Use `std::hypot()` for distance calculation. It's a little slower, but more accurate and more idiomatic.
- Let `time_to()` return the time for the full path up to that waypoint.
- Put the remainder of the algorithm all in one place.
- Run the algorithm front-to-back instead of storing the input and processing it back-to-front.
- Use a `std::vector` instead of a priority queue. You have to inspect all (non-pruned) items anyway.

Simplified waypoint struct:

```
struct Waypoint {
    double x, y, cost;
    
    static Waypoint read(std::istream &in) {
        double x, y, cost;
        in >> x >> y >> cost;
        return { x, y, cost };
    }
    
    double time_to(const Waypoint &other) const {
        return cost + delay + std::hypot(x - other.x, y - other.y) / speed;
    }
};
```

and algorithm:

```
void insert(Waypoint waypoint, std::vector<Waypoint>& waypoints) {
    double best = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();        
    for (auto& old : waypoints) {
        // Option 1: Find fastest route to newly inserted waypoint.
        best = std::min(best, old.time_to(waypoint));
        // Option 2: Keep old waypoint and incur penalty for skipping new one.
        old.cost += waypoint.cost;
    }
    // Prune old waypoints and insert new one with full path cost.
    std::erase_if(waypoints, [best](Waypoint old) { return old.cost > best + time_max; });
    waypoint.cost = best;
    waypoints.push_back(waypoint);
}
```

Create a vector, insert all points, then print the cost of the endpoint.

```
void process_streams(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {
    constexpr std::ios::iostate mask = std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit;
    in.exceptions(mask);
    out.exceptions(mask);

    for (;;) {
        int n;
        in >> n;
        if (n == 0) break;
        
        std::vector<Waypoint> waypoints;
        waypoints.push_back({ 0, 0, 0 });
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            insert(Waypoint::read(in), waypoints);
        insert({ 100, 100, 0 }, waypoints);
        
        out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << waypoints.back().cost << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think `std::hypot()` would be any slower (it can use FMA instructions which don't work with integers), but it would also not be any more accurate than OP's code.

Comment: This doesn't compile - `out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << waypoint.back().cost << std::endl;` refers to an undefined `waypoint`

Comment: When I fix your syntax errors, this only outputs `0.000`.

Comment: @Reinderien - Oops, sorry. I had an `&` missing in the signature of `insert()`, so the vector was passed by copy. I had also written `waypoint.back()` instead of `waypoints.back()` in `process_steams()`. Works now and produces the correct results. Things happen if you write without ever compiling it.

Comment: Thanks, it works. For the 1,000,000-rock dataset it's about 230% slower.

Comment: @Reinderien - 230% slower sounds about right. It is a bit higher than I expected, but in the ballpark. My goal was to remove all non-vital code without breaking asymptotic performance. I deliberately chose to prune in a separate pass over the vector to keep the code "as written" as close as possible to "as intended". I think the second pass is the main reason for the performance difference.