# Goats up hills II: revenge of the goat

Tags: c++, performance, interview-questions, c++20

This is a continuation of [Goat racing up a hill (C++ hiring take-home)](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/279459/goat-racing-up-a-hill-c-hiring-take-home) . This is an interview take-home challenge that has been translated to avoid compromising the company's question.

### Problem statement

You are a goat that needs to race up a hill. Designated waypoint rocks on the hill must each be visited in sequence (only in the order provided) or skipped and a score penalty incurred. For the goat to get its balance, it must pause ten seconds on each rock. Travel between rocks occurs on a straight line at two metres per second.

Coordinates and penalties per rock are all integral and exist in the open interval (0, 100). Rock designations are spatially unique*. The start rock at (0, 0) and the finish rock at (100, 100) are implied and not included in input.

Minimise the total cost of the goat's chosen path, calculated as the sum of all time spent and all penalties incurred.

Input is specified on `stdin` as one or more races followed by a final `0`. Each race is specified by an integer `n` on one line - the number of rocks (excluding the start and finish) - followed by `n` lines, each an integer triple `x y p`, the coordinates of the rock and the penalty incurred if it is skipped.

Output on `stdout` is a single line per race, the path cost to three digits after the decimal.

**Problem statement promises uniqueness but is contradicted by sample input that contains duplicates, so algorithm must work equally well in the presence of duplicates.*

### Test cases

Input (`sample_input_small.txt`):

```
1
50 50 20
3
30 30 90
60 60 80
10 90 100
3
30 30 90
60 60 80
10 90 10
0
```

Output (`sample_output_small.txt`):

```
90.711
156.858
110.711
```

### Implementation

I have a long-winded explainer that I might not paste here, but suffice to say that the implementation is amortised O(n). I used C++ because I need to catch up on best practices for versions 11+. The current compiler invocation looks like

```
 g++ -Ofast -s -march=native -NDEBUG --std=c++20 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
```

It's pretty fast - for the biggest well-formed input of 9801 rocks, it executes in 5ms. For a randomly-generated input of 1,000,000 waypoints, it's about 54 ms.

### Review

Any feedback welcome, but I'm particularly interested in idiomatic use of modern C++ and associated data structures, and performance.

I am not satisfied with a number of things:

Whereas this is much faster with the current heap approach than a prior iteration that used a `multimap`, the map was more elegant because it only required emplace and erase, not swapping. Consequences are numerous; I now need:

- assignment operators
- copy constructors
- mutable members
- special treatment of the case where the heap only contains one item

I'm sure there's a better way to do this; move semantics, rvalue references and auto constructors are still kind of black magic to me.

I took the most relevant parts of the first review, which were quite helpful. In a larger project I'd certainly cut out the tests to their own translation unit, but for the time being I'm preserving this as a single-file application.

To clarify some more: `<algorithm>` and `<vector>` were implied by other headers, and this does compile without them, but in a future version they will be reintroduced for better explicit dependency documentation. `sqrt`, `push_heap` and `pop_heap` being non-qualified references missing `std::` was an oversight, and frankly I'm a little disappointed that g++ didn't complain at me for doing so. (Is there a compiler flag to enforce this more strictly?)

### Code

```
#include <cassert>
#include <charconv>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <ranges>


using namespace std::string_view_literals;


namespace {
    constexpr int
        delay = 10,  // seconds
        speed = 2,   // metres per second
        edge = 100;  // metres

    /*
    These are theoretical bounds; we get narrower than this during the pruning step.
    We cannot use dist_min = 1, due to waypoints such as (4, 2) in
    sample_input_large.txt that violate the uniqueness constraint
    */
    constexpr double
        dist_min = 0,
        dist_max = edge*std::numbers::sqrt2,
        time_min = dist_min / speed,
        time_max = dist_max / speed;

    constexpr std::errc success = std::errc();


    double time_to(int dx, int dy) {
        assert(-edge <= dx); assert(dx <= edge);
        assert(-edge <= dy); assert(dy <= edge);

        // std::hypot(dx, dy) makes better use of the library but is much slower
        double time = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) / speed;
        assert(!std::isnan(time));
        assert(time_min <= time); assert(time <= time_max);

        return time;
    }


    int coord_min(int x) {
        return std::min(edge-x, x);
    }

    int coord_max(int x) {
        return std::max(edge-x, x);
    }


    // Direct representation of waypoints parsed from the input
    class Waypoint {
    private:
        int x, y, penalty;

    public:
        Waypoint(int x, int y, int penalty = 0): x(x), y(y), penalty(penalty) { }
        Waypoint(const Waypoint &other): x{other.x}, y(other.y), penalty(other.penalty) { }

        double time_to(const Waypoint &other) const {
            return ::time_to(other.x - x, other.y - y);
        }

        double time_min() const {
            return ::time_to(coord_min(x), coord_min(y));
        }

        double time_max() const {
            return ::time_to(coord_max(x), coord_max(y));
        }

        void output(std::ostream &out) const {
            out << '(' << x << ',' << y << ") penalty=" << penalty;
        }

        bool is_sane() const {
            return x >= 0 && x <= edge &&
                   y >= 0 && y <= edge;
        }

        int get_penalty() const { return penalty; }

        Waypoint &operator=(const Waypoint &other) {
            x = other.x;
            y = other.y;
            penalty = other.penalty;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Waypoint &w) {
        w.output(out);
        return out;
    }


    // Parser to replace the quite-slow istream << method
    class WaypointReader {
    private:
        static const std::invalid_argument parse_error;

        const std::string body_mem;
        const std::string_view body_view;
        long pos = 0;

    public:
        WaypointReader(const std::string &body_str):
            body_mem(body_str), body_view(body_mem) {
        }

        static WaypointReader from_stream(std::istream &in) {
            std::stringstream incopy;
            incopy << in.rdbuf();
            return WaypointReader(incopy.str());
        }

        int get_case_size() {
            size_t next_pos = body_view.find('\n', pos),
                   substr_len = next_pos - pos;
            std::string_view line = body_view.substr(pos, substr_len);
            const char *line_start = line.data(),
                       *line_end = line_start + substr_len;
            pos = next_pos + 1;

            int size;
            std::from_chars_result r = std::from_chars(line_start, line_end, size);
            if (r.ec != success || r.ptr != line_end)
                throw parse_error;

            return size;
        }

        Waypoint get_next() {
            size_t next_pos = body_view.find('\n', pos),
                   substr_len = next_pos - pos;
            std::string_view line = body_view.substr(pos, substr_len);
            const char *line_start = line.data(),
                       *line_end = line_start + substr_len;
            pos = next_pos+1;

            int x, y, penalty;
            std::from_chars_result r = std::from_chars(line_start, line_end, x);
            if (r.ec != success)
                throw parse_error;

            r = std::from_chars(r.ptr+1, line_end, y);
            if (r.ec != success)
                throw parse_error;

            r = std::from_chars(r.ptr+1, line_end, penalty);
            if (r.ec != success || r.ptr != line_end)
                throw parse_error;

            return Waypoint(x, y, penalty);
        }
    };

    const std::invalid_argument WaypointReader::parse_error("Invalid input line");


    // A sidekick to Waypoint that includes optimiser data. Only one "visited" Waypoint is held
    // in memory at a time, but a small handful of OptimisedWaypoints are held in a working map.
    class OptimisedWaypoint {
    public:
        Waypoint waypoint;
        double cost_invariant,  // Sum of invariant costs incurred by skipping from this waypoint
               cost_min;        // Lowest possible cost incurred by skipping from this waypoint to anywhere

        // cost_best is the cost of the optimal path from the beginning all the way here
        OptimisedWaypoint(const Waypoint &waypoint, double cost_best = 0):
            waypoint(waypoint), cost_invariant(cost_best - waypoint.get_penalty() + delay),
            cost_min(waypoint.time_min() + cost_invariant) { }

        OptimisedWaypoint(const OptimisedWaypoint &copy):
            waypoint(copy.waypoint),
            cost_invariant(copy.cost_invariant),
            cost_min(copy.cost_min) { }

        double cost_to(const Waypoint &visited) const {
            double time = visited.time_to(waypoint);
            return time + cost_invariant;
        }

        double cost_max() const {
            return waypoint.time_max() + cost_invariant;
        }

        void output(std::ostream &out) const {
            out << waypoint
                << " cost_inv=" << cost_invariant
                << " cost_min=" << cost_min;
        }

        bool is_sane() const {
            return waypoint.is_sane();
        }

        OptimisedWaypoint &operator=(const OptimisedWaypoint &other) {
            waypoint = other.waypoint;
            cost_invariant = other.cost_invariant;
            cost_min = other.cost_min;
            return *this;
        }

        bool operator<(const OptimisedWaypoint &other) const {
            return cost_invariant < other.cost_invariant;
        }
    };

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const OptimisedWaypoint &ow) {
        ow.output(out);
        return out;
    }


    // Erase all heap waypoints whose minimum cost is greater than to_exceed. to_exceed is the maximum cost of the
    // heap's front waypoint, having the lowest minimum cost of any optimised waypoint.
    void prune(std::vector<OptimisedWaypoint> &opt_heap, double to_exceed) {
        while (!opt_heap.empty()) {
            if (opt_heap.front().cost_min <= to_exceed)
                break;
            if (opt_heap.size() > 1)
                pop_heap(opt_heap.begin(), opt_heap.end());
            opt_heap.pop_back();
        }
    }


    double get_best_cost(
        const Waypoint &visited,
        const std::vector<OptimisedWaypoint> &opt_heap
    ) {
        double cost_best = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

        for (const OptimisedWaypoint &skip_from: opt_heap)
            cost_best = std::min(cost_best, skip_from.cost_to(visited));

        assert(cost_best < std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
        return cost_best;
    }


    double solve(WaypointReader &reader, int n) {
        int total_penalty = 0;

        const OptimisedWaypoint head(Waypoint(0, 0));

        // Max-heap of optimised waypoints with the first element
        // guaranteed to have highest minimum possible skip-from cost
        std::vector<OptimisedWaypoint> opt_heap { head };

        // The maximum acceptable cost, set as the maximum possible cost of the lowest-minimum-cost waypoint.
        // Any waypoints costing more than this are discarded.
        double cost_acceptable = std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),
               cost_front = head.cost_min;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
            Waypoint visited = reader.get_next();
            assert(visited.is_sane());
            total_penalty += visited.get_penalty();

            double cost_best = get_best_cost(visited, opt_heap);
            OptimisedWaypoint new_opt(visited, cost_best);
            assert(new_opt.is_sane());

            if (cost_acceptable >= new_opt.cost_min) {
                if (cost_front >= new_opt.cost_min) {
                    cost_front = new_opt.cost_min;
                    cost_acceptable = new_opt.cost_max();

                    // Only prune if the new waypoint has been accepted and has become the lowest-minimum-cost waypoint.
                    // Otherwise, the cost bounds will not have changed.
                    prune(opt_heap, cost_acceptable);
                }

                opt_heap.emplace_back(new_opt);
                push_heap(opt_heap.begin(), opt_heap.end());
            }
        }

        static const Waypoint tail(edge, edge);
        double cost_best = get_best_cost(tail, opt_heap);

        // Since waypoint costs are calculated with a negative relative penalty,
        // compensate by adding the total penalty to get the true cost
        return cost_best + total_penalty;
    }


    void process_streams(std::istream &in, std::ostream &out) {
        constexpr std::ios::iostate mask = std::ios::failbit | std::ios::badbit;
        in.exceptions(mask);
        out.exceptions(mask);
        out << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3);

        WaypointReader reader = WaypointReader::from_stream(in);

        for (;;) {
            int n = reader.get_case_size();
            if (n == 0) break;

            double time = solve(reader, n);
            out << time << '\n';
        }
    }


    void compare(std::istream &out_exp, std::istream &out_act) {
        for (;;) {
            std::string time_exp, time_act;
            if (!std::getline(out_exp, time_exp)) {
                if (out_exp.eof()) break;
                throw std::ios::failure("getline");
            }
            out_act >> time_act;
            std::cout << time_exp << " == " << time_act << std::endl;
            if (time_exp != time_act) {
                std::cerr << "Assertion failure" << std::endl;
                exit(1);
            }
        }
    }


    void test() {
        constexpr const char *cases[] = {"small", "medium", "large"};

        for (const char *const case_name: cases) {
            std::stringstream out_act;

            {
                std::ostringstream fnin;
                fnin << "samples/sample_input_" << case_name << ".txt";
                std::ifstream in;
                in.open(fnin.str());
                process_streams(in, out_act);
            }

            std::ostringstream fnout;
            fnout << "samples/sample_output_" << case_name << ".txt";
            std::ifstream out_exp;
            out_exp.exceptions(std::ios::badbit);
            out_exp.open(fnout.str());

            out_act.seekp(0);
            compare(out_exp, out_act);
        }
    }


    void process_std() {
        std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);  // Critical to fast handling of stdin
        process_streams(std::cin, std::cout);
    }
}


int main(int argc, const char **argv) {
    try {
        if (argc > 1 && argv[1] == "-t"sv)
            test();
        else process_std();
    } catch (const std::exception &ex) {
        std::cerr << ex.what() << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You say you're using a heap, but at first glance it looks like you're not using any of the standard library heap support (`std::priority_queue` and/or `std::make_heap()` etc.).  Is that right?

Comment: @TobySpeight yes. I'd love to use a priority queue but cannot, because I need to iterate over the contents

Comment: Makes sense - thanks for the explanation.  That's something that frustrates me from time to time.  I don't know whether the heap functions in `<algorithm>` are any help in this case.

Comment: I couldn't find your `push_heap()` and `pop_heap()` functions.

Comment: They're from <algorithm>, in a nested include from one of the other headers

Comment: Ah, so you meant `std::push_heap()` and `std::pop_heap()` respectively?  I thought you'd just omitted part of your code.  Also, I'm pretty sure no standard header is defined to transitively include `<algorithm>`, so you're in non-portable land there, too.

Comment: I've extended my answer to address the new paragraph you added.  I hope that is helpful.

Comment: Must the next waypoint always be above the last one?

Comment: @Deduplicator If by above you mean with a larger `y` value, then no; there is no guarantee about spatial arrangement other than the bounds stated. About the only such "above" we can guarantee is that the end node at (100, 100) is above everything else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’m going to assume the algorithm works correctly, and focus on the code structure.

So, let’s start at the top.

```
using namespace std::string_view_literals;
```

The literals namespaces are generally okay to expose globally via a `using` directive, but I would still suggest limiting them as much as possible, only putting them in function scopes. In this case, you use literally one string view literal, in `main()`, so I would put this line in `main()`.

```
namespace {
```

I don’t really see the point of putting the entire program in an anonymous namespace. I assume your thinking is that this makes everything statically scoped, which means it can be aggressively inlined, but it doesn’t really make any difference in reality. Anything that *can* be inlined, *will* (assuming even a moderately decent optimizer), regardless of whether it’s statically scoped or not. All that *really* happens is (for example) `Waypoint` just becomes `__secret_compiler_name::Waypoint`, and is consequently mangled as such. That’s literally it. Nothing else happens. Nothing. So it’s really not worth doing. (If you’re thinking “but the names won’t be exported then!”… wrong. Imagine you have a class `foo` in an anonymous namespace in a translation unit, and a function in that translation unit throws an instance of `foo`. How could that be possible if `foo` were truly not exported from the translation unit?)

In any case, it doesn’t really make a lot of sense to indent the *entire contents of a namespace*… and *especially* in a situation like this, when the content of the namespace is literally the entire program. All it does is cost you \$4 \times N\$ horizontal spaces of readability. For nothing.

I would suggest not indenting code within a namespace. Even in this simple case with a simple namespace, it will give you 4 more horizontal spaces, but in a case with multiple nested namespaces, indenting every namespace gets pathological.

```
    constexpr int
        delay = 10,  // seconds
        speed = 2,   // metres per second
        edge = 100;  // metres
```

This is an anti-pattern. [Declare only one variable per line](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration). It’s not only more readable, it avoids whole classes of typo-created bugs.

```
    constexpr std::errc success = std::errc();
```

This kind of thing isn’t a good idea. This is an example of a coding quirk designed to coddle clueless coders while frustrating experienced coders… exactly the opposite of what you want to be doing, because the people who are going to find the bugs in your code are far more likely to be the experiences coders, so they’re the ones you want to make things easy for.

For example, as someone who knows C++ fairly well, I just know that `r.ec == std::errc{}` is checking for success, as any moderately competent C++ coder does… but when I see `r.ec == success`, I have to stop, curse a bit, then search the entire freaking codebase for `success` (all while making sure it isn’t being shadowed in some sneaky way). These kinds of aliases don’t make code more readable, they make it *less* readable.

If you *really* **MUST** use a `success` alias, because you just can’t stand that `std::errc{}` means success, then fine, but in that case, the alias should be scoped to the function, not global. At least in that case, reviewers don’t need to go hunting through the entire codebase to figure out your disguise.

```
    double time_to(int dx, int dy) {
        assert(-edge <= dx); assert(dx <= edge);
        assert(-edge <= dy); assert(dy <= edge);

        // std::hypot(dx, dy) makes better use of the library but is much slower
        double time = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) / speed;
        assert(!std::isnan(time));
        assert(time_min <= time); assert(time <= time_max);

        return time;
    }
```

This entire function doesn’t really make a lot of sense, because you already have a `time_to()` function in the `Waypoint` class… where it belongs… although, oddly, you have it call out to *this* function. That’s kinda back-asswards. The whole point of strong typing and encapsulation is that, assuming everything is done properly, you shouldn’t need to reduce everything to `int`s and `double`s.

And, in fact, the very structure of this function is pretty much screaming that it’s a bad idea. You shouldn’t need a wash of `assert()`s to validate the input. The input should be valid by default. There should be no possible way—assuming no shenanigans—to have `dx` and `dy` be out of range. When more than 2∕3 of the function is `assert()`s… that’s a sign that something is smelly.

And if `dx` and `dy` are always in range, then there should be no possible way for `time` to be `NaN` or out of range.

(Also, [don’t put multiple statements on the same line](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl20-dont-place-two-statements-on-the-same-line).)

```
    int coord_min(int x) {
        return std::min(edge-x, x);
    }

    int coord_max(int x) {
        return std::max(edge-x, x);
    }
```

These two functions are hinting at a failure in your abstraction, but let’s put a pin in that and come back to them later.

```
    class Waypoint {
    private:
        int x, y, penalty;

    public:
        Waypoint(int x, int y, int penalty = 0): x(x), y(y), penalty(penalty) { }
        Waypoint(const Waypoint &other): x{other.x}, y(other.y), penalty(other.penalty) { }

        // ... [snip] ...

        void output(std::ostream &out) const {
            out << '(' << x << ',' << y << ") penalty=" << penalty;
        }

        Waypoint &operator=(const Waypoint &other) {
            x = other.x;
            y = other.y;
            penalty = other.penalty;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Waypoint &w) {
        w.output(out);
        return out;
    }
```

All of the above can be simplified to this:

```
    struct Waypoint
    {
        int x;
        int y;
        int penalty = 0;

        // ... [snip] ...

        friend auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, Waypoint const& w) -> std::ostream&
        {
            out << '(' << w.x << ',' << w.y << ") penalty=" << w.penalty;
            return out;
        }
    };
```

First, note that I’ve ditched the `output()` function, and just made the stream inserter a friend. Also, [a *hidden* friend](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/hidden-friends.html).

Second, I ditched the manual copy constructor and assignment. These serve no purpose, and in fact, defining them creates problems: it inhibits move operations, and now the copy ops are no longer trivial ops. The rule is to [never define any of the copy constructor, copy assignment operator, move constructor, move assignment operator, or destructor unless you absolutely need to](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c20-if-you-can-avoid-defining-default-operations-do)… and [if you define *any* of them, you must define *all* of them](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c21-if-you-define-or-delete-any-copy-move-or-destructor-function-define-or-delete-them-all).

Third, and this will probably be the only controversial move, I made all the data members public. Here’s my rationale:

If there is no class invariant that can be broken by fuggering with any of a class’s data members, then they should all be public. For example, consider a 3D point class with `x`, `y`, and `z` members. There is no possible way to “break” a point. No matter what value you set `x` to, it’s still a valid point. Doesn’t matter what `y` and `z` are. In other words, it is impossible to set any of the data members to any valid value and break the class, and not have a valid point. Thus, there is no reason to make those data members private. By contrast, consider a date class with `year`, `month`, `day` members. It is possible to break the class invariant and create an invalid date by—for example—setting the day to 30 when the month is February. In other words, it is possible to set one of the data members to a valid value (30 is a perfectly cromulent day value), yet break the class. To protect the class invariant, you can’t allow free access to the individual data members. Thus, those data members *should* be private. ([See also here](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c2-use-class-if-the-class-has-an-invariant-use-struct-if-the-data-members-can-vary-independently).)

Now let’s consider your way point class. It’s basically a 2D point plus a penalty value. As with the 3D point, there is no possible way to break the class invariant by messing with any of those individual data members. So long as you set *any* of `x`, `y`, or `penalty` to *any* valid value, the entire way point object is valid.

Ah, but there’s a catch, right? There are invalid values for `x`, `y`, and `penalty`. Both `x` and `y` have to be between `0` and `edge`, right? And `penalty` can’t be less than zero, presumably. So while it is true that it is impossible to set any data member to a valid value and end up with an invalid way point… there *are* invalid values. So how do we guard against that?

There are two options.

Option 1 is less elegant. This is where you make all the data members private, and provide constructors and accessors to prevent invalid values. This… “works”, and is probably the “easy way”. It requires a lot more code in the class, and hence, a lot more testing of the class. But it’ll do the job.

Option 2 is more interesting.

Here’s where I call back to those `coord_min()` and `coord_max()` functions, and all those `assert()`s, and point out that there is an object in your abstraction screaming out to be noticed. You have values… specifically coordinates (for now!)… that are *basically* `int`s… but that must be restricted to certain value ranges. Right off the bat, that means you really need a `coordinate_value` type… you shouldn’t be using bare `int`s for things that are clearly *not* bare `int`s (because they must be restricted to a certain range).

So, to *start*, you should have this:

```
using coordinate_value = int;
```

That’s just the most absolute basic starting point. But with that, you should be defining things like `Waypoint` like this:

```
struct Waypoint
{
    coordinate_value x;
    coordinate_value y;
    penalty_value penalty;

    // ... etc. ...
};
```

Now, using an alias of a bare `int` is only slightly better than using a bare `int`. So, the next step is this:

```
class coordinate_value
{
    int _value = /* optional sensible default */;

public:
    constexpr coordinate_value() noexcept = default;

    // Explicit conversion from int.
    constexpr explicit coordinate_value(int v) : _value{v}
    {
        // Validate here.
    }

    // Implicit conversion to int.
    constexpr operator int() const noexcept
    {
        return _value;
    }
};
```

And you can build it up from there with whatever else you need: comparisons, arithmetic operations, stream inserters/extractors, whatever.

With that (and a similar class for `penalty_value`, your way point class is trivial, as shown above—just a simple `struct` with a few public members—yet is perfectly safe, and maximally efficient. You can’t possibly create an invalid way point, and you can’t *make* an extant way point invalid… so you can just always assume that your way point is valid. Which means you no longer need `assert()`s and other sanity checks all over the place. And, in fact, the compiler can leverage the knowledge that way points and their data are always valid (possibly with some help from you via something like [the proposed `[[assume(expr)]]`](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p1774r8.pdf)) to do more aggressive optimizing.

But, hang on a sec. We have `coordinate_value`, which is basically an `int` clamped to the range [0, 100]. And we also have `penalty_value`, which is basically an `int` clamped to the range [0, ∞] (well, not really infinity, but `std::numeric_limits<int>::max()`, but, yanno).

So, what we *really* need is a `clamped_value` type, that might look something like this to start:

```
// Some helper concepts that are just generally useful.
template <typename T>
concept character = std::same_as<T, char>
    or std::same_as<T, char8_t>
    or std::same_as<T, char16_t>
    or std::same_as<T, char32_t>
    or std::same_as<T, wchar_t>;

template <typename T>
concept number = std::integral<T> or std::floating_point<T>
    and (not character<T> and not std::same_as<T, bool>);

template <number auto Min, number auto Max>
    requires std::same_as<decltype(Min), decltype(Max)>
        and (Min <= Max)
class clamped_value
{
    T _value = Min;

public:
    constexpr coordinate_value() noexcept = default;

    // Explicit conversion from value.
    constexpr explicit coordinate_value(T v) : _value{std::move(v)}
    {
        // Validate here.
    }

    // Implicit conversion to value.
    constexpr operator T() const noexcept
    {
        return _value;
    }
};
```

And you can jazz up that type as much you need, such as adding support for open and closed ranges, and special casing having no minimum or no maximum, or whatever. Getting this type right has such an enormous payoff, it probably deserves to be its own project.

With that, `coordinate_value` becomes:

```
using coordinate_value = clamped_value<0, edge>;
```

And, of course, the way point class is just a `struct` with public `coordinate_value` (and `penalty_value` members), and everything Just Works™.

Which turns all this:

```
    double time_to(int dx, int dy) {
        assert(-edge <= dx); assert(dx <= edge);
        assert(-edge <= dy); assert(dy <= edge);

        // std::hypot(dx, dy) makes better use of the library but is much slower
        double time = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) / speed;
        assert(!std::isnan(time));
        assert(time_min <= time); assert(time <= time_max);

        return time;
    }


    int coord_min(int x) {
        return std::min(edge-x, x);
    }

    int coord_max(int x) {
        return std::max(edge-x, x);
    }


    // Direct representation of waypoints parsed from the input
    class Waypoint {
    private:
        int x, y, penalty;

    public:
        Waypoint(int x, int y, int penalty = 0): x(x), y(y), penalty(penalty) { }
        Waypoint(const Waypoint &other): x{other.x}, y(other.y), penalty(other.penalty) { }

        double time_to(const Waypoint &other) const {
            return ::time_to(other.x - x, other.y - y);
        }

        double time_min() const {
            return ::time_to(coord_min(x), coord_min(y));
        }

        double time_max() const {
            return ::time_to(coord_max(x), coord_max(y));
        }

        void output(std::ostream &out) const {
            out << '(' << x << ',' << y << ") penalty=" << penalty;
        }

        bool is_sane() const {
            return x >= 0 && x <= edge &&
                   y >= 0 && y <= edge;
        }

        int get_penalty() const { return penalty; }

        Waypoint &operator=(const Waypoint &other) {
            x = other.x;
            y = other.y;
            penalty = other.penalty;
            return *this;
        }
    };

    std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Waypoint &w) {
        w.output(out);
        return out;
    }
```

into something like this:

```
struct waypoint
{
    using coordinate_value = clamped_value<0, edge>;
    using penalty_value    = clamped_value<clamp_minimum{0}>;

    coordinate_value x;
    coordinate_value y;
    penalty_value    penalty;

    // Can be constexpr as of C++23.
    auto time_to(waypoint const& w) const
    {
        auto const dx = w.x - x;
        auto const dy = w.y - y;
    
        return std::sqrt((dx * dx) + (dy * dy)) / speed;
    }

    friend auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, Waypoint const& w) -> std::ostream&
    {
        out << '(' << w.x << ',' << w.y << ") penalty=" << w.penalty;
        return out;
    }
};
```

(with the reusable `clamped_value` type separately defined in some other module/header, of course).

And ironically, this much shorter code should be *faster*, because all the fundamental ops except construction are trivial.

Oh, one more thing:

```
        Waypoint(const Waypoint &other): x{other.x}, y(other.y), penalty(other.penalty) { }
```

[The norm in C++ is to put the type modifier with the type… not the identifier](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#nl18-use-c-style-declarator-layout). In other words:

- `const Waypoint &other`: this is C style.
- `const Waypoint& other`: this is C++ style.
- `Waypoint const& other`: also C++ style.

```
    // Parser to replace the quite-slow istream << method
    class WaypointReader {
    private:
        static const std::invalid_argument parse_error;

        const std::string body_mem;
        const std::string_view body_view;
        long pos = 0;

    public:
        WaypointReader(const std::string &body_str):
            body_mem(body_str), body_view(body_mem) {
        }

        static WaypointReader from_stream(std::istream &in) {
            std::stringstream incopy;
            incopy << in.rdbuf();
            return WaypointReader(incopy.str());
        }

        int get_case_size() {
            size_t next_pos = body_view.find('\n', pos),
                   substr_len = next_pos - pos;
            std::string_view line = body_view.substr(pos, substr_len);
            const char *line_start = line.data(),
                       *line_end = line_start + substr_len;
            pos = next_pos + 1;

            int size;
            std::from_chars_result r = std::from_chars(line_start, line_end, size);
            if (r.ec != success || r.ptr != line_end)
                throw parse_error;

            return size;
        }

        Waypoint get_next() {
            size_t next_pos = body_view.find('\n', pos),
                   substr_len = next_pos - pos;
            std::string_view line = body_view.substr(pos, substr_len);
            const char *line_start = line.data(),
                       *line_end = line_start + substr_len;
            pos = next_pos+1;

            int x, y, penalty;
            std::from_chars_result r = std::from_chars(line_start, line_end, x);
            if (r.ec != success)
                throw parse_error;

            r = std::from_chars(r.ptr+1, line_end, y);
            if (r.ec != success)
                throw parse_error;

            r = std::from_chars(r.ptr+1, line_end, penalty);
            if (r.ec != success || r.ptr != line_end)
                throw parse_error;

            return Waypoint(x, y, penalty);
        }
    };

    const std::invalid_argument WaypointReader::parse_error("Invalid input line");
```

I’m truly baffled by this class. The comment says its purpose is to be faster than using multiple `istream` extraction operations, which… fine… but… the way it’s done is by reading the ***ENTIRE*** input into *another* stream… and then *copying* the contents of that stream into a string… and then copying that string into *another* string… all to eventually get a string view you can work with. I’m actually impressed that all that works out faster than using `istream` extractors (but not shocked, because the costs of locale-awareness in `istream`s is *really* high).

I think you need to take a step back and rethink all this.

First, you need a type to store each race, which is really just a vector of waypoints, but, again, this is C++, so you really need a bespoke type for this:

```
class race
{
    std::vector<waypoint> _waypoints;

public:

    // ... etc. ...

    friend auto operator>>(std::istream& in, race& r) -> std::istream&
    {
        // ... TODO ...
    }
};
```

With that, your actual main loop is just:

```
for (auto r = race{}; (in >> r); )
{
    auto const best_time = race.solve();

    out << best_time << "\n";
}
```

That’s it.

You see, there’s no real reason to make the loading of *multiple* races efficient *as a whole*. Once loading a *single* race is as efficient as can be, you’re hardly going to notice the comparatively microscopic extra cost of loading additional races.

Where the efficiency magic happens, then, is in that single race loading operation. And for *that*, all you need is this:

```
    friend auto operator>>(std::istream& in, race& r) -> std::istream&
    {
        // We put this here, outside of all loops, so we can reuse its memory.
        // In other words, in theory, the only time a reallocation will be
        // necessary is when we're reading a line that is longer than any
        // previously read line. Which should be a rare occurrence after the
        // first few lines.
        //
        // We could do even better by noting the maximum expected length of a
        // valid line, which would be "100 100 100\n", which is 12 chars, and
        // reserve that up front. (Though that's within SSO range.)
        auto line = std::string{};

        if (std::getline(line, in))
        {
            auto size = int{};
            if (auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(line.data(), line.data() + line.size(), size); ec != std::errc{})
            {
                if (size == 0)
                {
                    in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
                    return in;
                }

                // could do further validation of size and p here...

                auto waypoints = std::vector<waypoint>{};
                waypoints.resize(size);

                for (auto& wp : waypoints)
                {
                    if (not std::getline(line, in))
                    {
                        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
                        return in;
                    }

                    auto p_next_char = line.data();
                    auto const p_end = line.data() + line.size()

                    auto x = int{};
                    if (auto [p, ec] = std::from_chars(p_next_char, p_end, size); ec != std::errc{})
                    {
                        // validate x here...

                        p_next_char = p;
                        if (p_next_char != p_end)
                            ++p_next_char; // ignore space
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
                        return in;
                    }

                    // exactly the same as above for y and penalty (yeah,
                    // iostreams code is always ugly, verbose, and repetitive)

                    wp = waypoint{x, y, penalty};
                }

                r._waypoints = std::move(waypoints);
            }
            else
            {
                in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
                return in;
            }
        }

        return in;
    }
```

The above is fairly restrictive on the input format (just like your code), but I doubt you can get much faster than that.

(Of course, if you are *actually* going to write an istream extractor, there is a lot you can do to avoid a lot of the repetition.)

With that, you can throw the whole `WaypointReader` class out completely. But I’ll review it anyway.

```
        static const std::invalid_argument parse_error;
```

As with `success`, I really don’t see the point of this. Presumably, parse errors will be very rare… exceptionally rare, even… and when they happen, everything is about to come crashing down anyway, so what’s the point of bailing out of the program *efficiently*? For all valid and successful runs of the program *you will never need this exception*. So why pay the cost for it?

Also, `std::invalid_argument` is not the correct exception to use in any case. `std::invalid_argument` is a *logic* error… meaning it signals an error in the logic of the program. (Specifically, an invalid argument was passed to a function.) But there is nothing wrong with the *program*… the problem here is that the program’s input data is bad. This is a *run-time* error. There isn’t really a standard error that is purpose specific for malformed input data, though you could use either `std::runtime_error` or `std::ios_base::failure` or, perhaps better, `std::system_error` with a domain-specific error code.

```
        const std::string body_mem;
        const std::string_view body_view;
```

[Don’t make data members `const`](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#c12-dont-make-data-members-const-or-references).

I know, I know, I’ve seen a lot of well-meaning but confused people spreading misinformation about how data members should be `const`. I’ve seen arguments about safety and correctness… which are silly, because if you want `const` data, you make the *object* `const`, not the object’s data members… and I’ve seen arguments about efficiency and optimization… which are flat-out wrong, and easily disproved.

I’ve linked to the part of the core guidelines—peer-reviewed by the top C++ experts in the world, and edited by two of the best, including Bjarne Stroustrup himself—that explains why this is a bad idea.

The other big problem here is having a `std::string_view` data member. That’s just juggling lit dynamite. `std::string_view` is what’s referred to by the experts as a “parameter-only type”, which means that it is really intended for use *only* as a function parameter, and using it for anything else is *extremely* dangerous. (Though, obviously having a local variable string view of a string that is in scope and unmodified (ie, `const`) for the entire scope is fine.)

In this particular case, consider what would happen if you ever copied a `WaypointReader` class. You’d copy the string, but the string *view* would still be viewing the *original* string, not the copy. If the original now goes out of scope, boom, there goes your program.

```
        WaypointReader(const std::string &body_str):
            body_mem(body_str), body_view(body_mem) {
        }
```

First, this constructor should be `explicit`.

Second, when taking an object as a sink value—as you are here with the string—the best way to do it is to take it by value and move it. Consider what happens in this case. Somehow someone has constructed a string containing the input data… you take it by `const&`… and because it a `const&`, you have to *copy* it into `body_mem`. If you took it by value, you could *move* it into `body_mem`, which could be *massively* faster for very large strings, and save a lot of memory.

```
        static WaypointReader from_stream(std::istream &in) {
            std::stringstream incopy;
            incopy << in.rdbuf();
            return WaypointReader(incopy.str());
        }
```

As I mentioned above, I’m actually impressed that this is noticeably faster than doing stream extractions manually, because what you’re doing here is copying *an entire stream*… and then again copying that entire stream’s data into a string. Yikes.

If you are determined to read *the entire stream* into a string, well, there’s no way to avoid copying the entire stream of course. *However*, you can avoid the *second* copy, and just yank the string right out of the string stream, like so:

```
return WaypointReader(std::move(incopy).str());
```

On to `get_case_size()`:

```
            size_t next_pos = body_view.find('\n', pos),
                   substr_len = next_pos - pos;
```

Oh, please don’t write code like this. This is just ghastly.

There is absolutely no benefit of the above over:

```
            auto const next_pos   = body_view.find('\n', pos);
            auto const substr_len = next_pos - pos;
```

And the latter is much less bug-prone.

(Also, for the record, it’s `std::size_t`. But there’s no reason not to just use `auto`.)

```
            std::string_view line = body_view.substr(pos, substr_len);
```

As far as I can tell, this (and the identical line in `get_next()`) is the only reason for `body_view`. But if all you want is a view of part of the string, you could just do:

```
            auto const next_pos   = body_mem.find('\n', pos);
            auto const substr_len = next_pos - pos;

            auto const line = std::string_view{body_mem.data() + pos, substr_len};
```

Of course, that raises the question of whether you even need the view at all, since you just end up working with pointers anyway. You could just ditch the line view, and change the following (ghastly) line to get this:

```
            auto const next_pos   = body_mem.find('\n', pos);
            auto const substr_len = next_pos - pos;

            auto const line_start = body_mem.data() + pos;
            auto const line_end   = line_start + substr_len;
```

And from there the rest of the function is unchanged.

`get_next()` is almost the same, except there’s this:

```
            int x, y, penalty;
```

First, [don’t declare multiple variables like this](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es10-declare-one-name-only-per-declaration).

Second, [don’t declare variables until you need them](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es21-dont-introduce-a-variable-or-constant-before-you-need-to-use-it). You don’t need either `y` or `penalty` until later in the function.

And third, avoid declaring variables like `type name;`. That is a dangerous pattern, because it leaves some variables uninitialized. You can get away with it here, because you go on to set those variables with `std::from_chars()`, but it’s still bad practice.

Also, as an aside, reusing a `std::from_chars_result` seems a bit pathological. Those are intended to be throwaway objects that you check-and-discard… not the type of thing you usually truck around and reuse for 3∕4 of a function. [Reusing variables is also an anti-pattern](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#es26-dont-use-a-variable-for-two-unrelated-purposes).

```
    class OptimisedWaypoint {
```

So this class is just an implementation detail of the solve algorithm; it doesn’t need to (and shouldn’t) be part of the public interface. For that reason, I wouldn’t bother spending too much time spiffing it up. (Indeed, personally I wouldn’t bother making a class at all. I’d just use a `tuple<Waypoint, double, double>`.)

Everything that applied to `Waypoint` applies here: you don’t need the copy constructor or copy assignment operator. Since you don’t change the waypoint at any time after initialization, there is no need to check whether it’s “sane”; if it was sane at construction time, it will be sane always.

```
    // Erase all heap waypoints whose minimum cost is greater than to_exceed. to_exceed is the maximum cost of the
    // heap's front waypoint, having the lowest minimum cost of any optimised waypoint.
    void prune(std::vector<OptimisedWaypoint> &opt_heap, double to_exceed) {
        while (!opt_heap.empty()) {
            if (opt_heap.front().cost_min <= to_exceed)
                break;
            if (opt_heap.size() > 1)
                pop_heap(opt_heap.begin(), opt_heap.end());
            opt_heap.pop_back();
        }
    }
```

I have to admit I have no idea what the logic here is. From the comment, and as far as I can tell from the actual code, all you’re doing is removing every way point whose minimum cost is above a certain value. Yet, bizarrely, you do so by checking the first element, and if that’s above the limit, you *rearrange the entire data set* to remove it… then do that *again*, checking the first element, and if it’s above the limit, rearranging the entire data set… and so on. Surely there’s a better way to do this.

It seems like all you have to do is remove all costly way points, then remake the heap, like so:

```
auto const num_erased = std::erase_if(opt_heap,
    [to_exceed](auto&& wp) { return wp.cost_min > to_exceed; });

// Only need to bother remaking the heap if something was actually erased.
if (num_erased != 0)
    std::ranges::make_heap(opt_heap);
```

Now if it actually turns out remaking the heap is more expensive than repeatedly popping, you can still do better by counting the number of offending way points first, then popping as many times as necessary:

```
auto const n = std::ranges::count_if(opt_heap,
    [to_exceed](auto cost_min) { return cost_min > to_exceed; },
    &Waypoint::cost_min);

auto p_end = std::ranges::end(opt_heap);
for (auto i = decltype(n){}; i != n; ++i)
    std::ranges::pop_heap(std::ranges::begin(opt_heap), p_end--);

opt_heap.erase(p_end, std::ranges::end(opt_heap);
```

Either way is probably both simpler and more efficient.

(One wonders if you even need a heap in the first place. It seems like you could achieve the same effect, and probably more efficiently, by just sorting by the cost and using binary search algorithms. But, as I said, I’m not reviewing the algorithm, just the structure.)

```
    double get_best_cost(
        const Waypoint &visited,
        const std::vector<OptimisedWaypoint> &opt_heap
    ) {
        double cost_best = std::numeric_limits<double>::max();

        for (const OptimisedWaypoint &skip_from: opt_heap)
            cost_best = std::min(cost_best, skip_from.cost_to(visited));

        assert(cost_best < std::numeric_limits<double>::max());
        return cost_best;
    }
```

Is it ever possible for `cost_to()` to return `std::numeric_limits<double>::max()`? If not, then the `assert()` is unnecessary, because all it’s checking is `assert(not opt_heap.empty())`.

In any case, you should avoid raw loops like this, and prefer algorithms. In this case, `reduce()` would probably be the best choice, if it were properly integrated with ranges:

```
// Not C++20 code, unfortunately:
auto const cost_best = std::ranges::reduce(
    opt_heap
        | std::views::transform([&visited](auto&& wp) { return wp.cost_to(visited); }),
    std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),
    [](auto c1, auto c2) { return std::min(c1, c2); }
);
```

If you could do that, you could even use an execution policy like `std::execution::par_unseq` to possibly parallelize or vectorize the algorithm.

But because the numerics algorithms haven’t been spiffied up yet, you’re stuck with `accumulate()`, and no reordering, parallelization, or vectorization:

```
auto const cost_best = std::accumulate(
    std::ranges::begin(opt_heap),
    std::ranges::end(opt_heap),
    std::numeric_limits<double>::max(),
    [&visited](auto const& skip_from, auto cost)
    {
        return std::min(cost, skip_from.cost_to(visited))
    });
```

There’s not much more to add for the rest of the code. I’ve already covered the important stuff (like doing input), and everything else is just going to be repeating stuff mentioned previously.

## Extension (2022-09-16)

### Anonymous namespaces and exported symbols

So, the issue here is I claimed that things in anonymous namespaces can still be exported from translation units, and the OP called me on that, saying:

> Removing the namespace introduces an additional 9 entries in `.symtab`, including things like `_Z5solveR14WaypointReaderi` and `_ZlsRSoRK8Waypoint`. Those sure seem like exported class symbols to me, and they're very much absent from the program when compiled with the anonymous namespace.

The problem here is we’re talking about two different things.

I was talking about *C++* exports—that is, language-level exports—where symbols exported from one translation unit are visible in another. In C++, symbols are exported by default, unless you declare them `static` or put them in an anonymous namespace. Symbols from other translation units are *imported* using `extern` (for objects) or declarations (for classes/functions). (There also *used* to be a way to export templates, but that was removed in C++11.) What I was explaining was that even though using an anonymous namespace “hides” symbols from being accessed *directly* from other translation units, they’re still very much accessible indirectly. (I used the example of throwing an instance of a “hidden” class, but there are other ways, too.)

What the OP is talking about is something entirely different, and completely unrelated. They probably used a tool like `readelf` or `objdump` or `nm` to inspect the generated executable, and saw a bunch of stuff in `.symtab` or `.dynsym`. *Those* are not C++ exports. Those are *linker* exports. In fact, they have no relation to C++ at all, and could have been generated by other languages. And, in fact, even when using C++, what gets generated has nothing at all to do with C++, but is rather a function of the *linker* (and compiler and optimizer, all working together).

To prove the point, take the source code from the OP, put it in a file called `src.cpp`, and compile it with this command:

```sh
g++ --std=c++20 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Ofast src.cpp
```

Then list the symbols with:

```sh
readelf -CWs a.out
```

That shows you everything in `.dynsym` and `.symtab`. I have 86 entries in `.dynsym`, and 132 entries in `.symtab`. Nothing from the source code in the file is in `.dynsym`, so let’s focus on the entries in `.symtab` with “Waypoint”. You can do that with `readelf -CWs a.out | grep Waypoint`.

This is what I get:

```
     6: 0000000000004140   302 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::get_best_cost((anonymous namespace)::Waypoint const&, std::vector<(anonymous namespace)::OptimisedWaypoint, std::allocator<(anonymous namespace)::OptimisedWaypoint> > const&)
     8: 000000000000a3a0     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 guard variable for (anonymous namespace)::solve((anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader&, int)::tail
     9: 000000000000a3a8    12 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 (anonymous namespace)::solve((anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader&, int)::tail
    11: 000000000000a3c0    16 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 (anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader::parse_error
```

(For reference, that’s 1 function, and 3 global or function static variables. Only 2 “real” variables are exported: the `WaypointReader::parse_error` exception object, and `tail` in `solve()`. The “guard” variable is necessary because `tail` has to only be initialized once, even if the function is called multiple times; it’s basically just a (probably atomic) flag.)

It’s important to understand that these symbols have no effect on the actual program. Their presence or absence does not make the program run any faster, or use any less memory while running. *Maybe* they affect the cost of the kernel *loading* the program—maybe that takes a little longer or uses more memory—but if you’re worried about *that* kind of cost… you probably should be coding in ASM and not C++. (To be clear, I’m pretty sure `.symtab` is *not* loaded into memory when a program is run, but I’m saying that its mere existence may require a little more work on the part of the loader to spot it and work around it. Not much work, but maybe non-zero.)

It’s also important to understand that these symbols are actually only *local* symbols. They are in `.symtab`… not `.dynsym`. They are not “exported” in the sense that symbols exported from a shared library that you can call are.

Now, as the OP noted, if you remove the anonymous namespace and compile again, you will now get *12* symbols with `Waypoint`. So, the anonymous namespace really matters, right?

Wrong. Take the original code, and instead of using the compile command above, use this one:

```sh
g++ --std=c++20 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -O0 src.cpp
```

The only difference from the previous compile command is `-O0` instead of `-Ofast`.

Now try listing the symbols, and…:

```
    24: 0000000000003b7e    49 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::Waypoint(int, int, int)
    25: 0000000000003b7e    49 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::Waypoint(int, int, int)
    26: 0000000000003bb0    55 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::Waypoint((anonymous namespace)::Waypoint const&)
    27: 0000000000003bb0    55 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::Waypoint((anonymous namespace)::Waypoint const&)
    28: 0000000000003be8    69 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::time_to((anonymous namespace)::Waypoint const&) const
    29: 0000000000003c2e    67 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::time_min() const
    30: 0000000000003c72    67 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::time_max() const
    31: 0000000000003cb6   129 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::output(std::ostream&) const
    32: 0000000000003d38    66 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::is_sane() const
    33: 0000000000003d7a    17 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::get_penalty() const
    34: 0000000000003d8c    58 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint::operator=((anonymous namespace)::Waypoint const&)
    35: 0000000000003dc6    45 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::operator<<(std::ostream&, (anonymous namespace)::Waypoint const&)
    36: 0000000000003df4    82 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader::WaypointReader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
    37: 0000000000003df4    82 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader::WaypointReader(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)
    38: 0000000000003e46    27 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader::~WaypointReader()
…
```

I cut it short, but it was 130 symbols for me. So much for the anonymous namespace making any difference to what gets put in the symbol table.

Now, you may say that was unfair, because I turned off *all* optimization. Okay. Fine. Try it with just `-O` instead:

```
    13: 00000000000039aa   141 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 (anonymous namespace)::get_best_cost((anonymous namespace)::Waypoint const&, std::vector<(anonymous namespace)::OptimisedWaypoint, std::allocator<(anonymous namespace)::OptimisedWaypoint> > const&)
    14: 0000000000003a38    33 FUNC    LOCAL  DEFAULT   16 std::_Vector_base<(anonymous namespace)::OptimisedWaypoint, std::allocator<(anonymous namespace)::OptimisedWaypoint> >::~_Vector_base()
    16: 000000000000a3c0    16 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 (anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader::parse_error
    17: 000000000000a3a0     8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 guard variable for (anonymous namespace)::solve((anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader&, int)::tail
    18: 000000000000a3a8    12 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   28 (anonymous namespace)::solve((anonymous namespace)::WaypointReader&, int)::tail
```

So, *5* symbols, not 4 (as you get with `-Ofast`).

I just used different optimization levels to prove the point, but *any* compiler/linker options could have *any* effect. (Give `-fwhole-program` a try without the anonymous namespace, for example.) What controls which symbols get put in the symbol table by the linker is a complex dance between the code, the compiler, the optimizer, and the linker. The anonymous namespace *happens* to work in your favour here (for this particular version of the compiler and linker)… but it is not *actually* controlling what does and does not end up in the symbol table. What *actually* controls that is the options you give to the compiler and linker (and, indirectly, the optimizer).

Changing your C++ code to control what the linker puts in the symbol table is like an author changing the plot of their novel to work around the fact that the “W” key on their typewriter is faulty (“And the murderer is… William! No, wait, shit. Can’t type that name, so, uh, I guess Steve did it instead.”). Do not be a slave to the limitations of your tools. Just write good C++ code. It’s not only silly to uglify your code as an underhanded way of controlling the linker, it’s actually self-defeating, because maybe the next version of GCC will work in an entirely different way, making your hack at least pointless, and possibly making things worse.

(Caveat: If you are targeting a specific compiler/linker, then okay, sure, fine, you can tweak your code to satisfy that. But understand that doing so may improve codegen for *that particular* compiler/linker, but actually make things worse for other tools. This comes up often when having to work around bugs in tools, too. It’s quite common that you have to write *worse* code to make older/buggy compilers work, instead of *good* code that has better codegen properties in newer/better compilers.)

If you want to control what the linker generates… just control the linker directly. Don’t try to do so indirectly by warping your code.

In this particular case, what’s in `.symtab` has absolutely no relevance to how your program runs… but if you’re *really* bothered by the fact that there’s crap in there: just strip it out. Just add `-s` to your link command, or use `strip`. Problem solved.

### Never, ever use `exit()`

I made a mental note to mention this, but then forgot about it. In `compare()` you call `exit(1)`.

Now, first, that should be `std::exit(1)`.

But the real problem is that `std::exit()` is extremely dangerous to use in C++, because it can cause destructors to not be run… which can be *catastrophic*. You should never, ever use `std::exit()` in a C++ program.

And in this case, there’s no need for it anyway. Instead of:

```
            if (time_exp != time_act) {
                std::cerr << "Assertion failure" << std::endl;
                exit(1);
            }
```

you can just do:

```
            if (time_exp != time_act)
                throw std::runtime_error{"Assertion failure"};
```

That’s not only better, it’s also less code.

Incidentally, “1” is not a portable exit code. The only portable return codes from `main()` are `EXIT_SUCCESS`, `EXIT_FAILURE`, and `0` (which means success, but is not necessarily the same as `EXIT_SUCCESS`).

### Miscellaneous other stuff

```
auto operator<<(std::ostream& out, Waypoint const& w) -> std::ostream&
```

This is [trailing return style](https://www.danielsieger.com/blog/2022/01/28/cpp-trailing-return-types.html). It has nothing to do with the return type being ambiguous. In this case, it means the same thing as the “classic” function style:

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Waypoint const& w)
```

However, trailing return style has several benefits over the “classic” style (which is why they created it in the first place), and no real downsides (other than that it’s a few chars longer).

As for the unused function warning comment… you are expecting too much of that warning. It isn’t a tool to detect functions that are never used in the program. It will only fire for functions that are absolutely and utterly impossible to be used anywhere other than the immediate scope they are in (and, obviously, aren’t used in that scope). In other words, it doesn’t mean “this function is never used”, it means “this function *can never BE used*”, which is subtly different, but different.

In this case, it was firing because the anonymous namespace means that anything in that namespace cannot be called outside of the translation unit. So anything in that namespace that isn’t used in the translation unit cannot possibly be used… anywhere… ever.

If you want to find *actually* unused functions (as in, not just “can’t possibly be used”, but also “could possibly be used, but isn’t”), you need to use a proper tool for that, like a static analyzer.

Comment: Right; from the top: re. namespaces and _Nothing else happens_, that's untrue - and I've tested it. I'll dig up the difference in the symbol table again, just for kicks, since you seem so convinced.

Comment: Removing the namespace introduces an additional 9 entries in `.symtab`, including things like `_Z5solveR14WaypointReaderi` and `_ZlsRSoRK8Waypoint`. Those sure seem like exported class symbols to me, and they're very much absent from the program when compiled with the anonymous namespace.

Comment: What is the purpose of `operator<<` having an `auto ->`? The `ostream &` return type doesn't seem ambiguous.

Comment: Having `operator<<` as a `friend` is nice, and offers an unexpected benefit(ish): `g++` no longer warns that that's an unused function (though that's actually a toss-up for developers looking to cut out unused code)

Comment: `assert()` isn't (or at least shouldn't) be used to _validate_ input.  I read it here as documenting the programmer's assumptions/understanding at that point; it's basically a formalised comment (that comes with a checking facility in debug builds).

Comment: Ah, so *that’s* why you’re using an anonymous namespace. Okay, this is going to take a lot of explanation to clear up, so I’ll extend the answer. (There’s also other stuff I should probably add that I forgot to mention.)

Comment: Right, well. This is kind of a novel, and I do appreciate the effort and detail you've invested here. Things I like and have adopted: throw instead of exit, move() (saves about 1ms), semantic typedefs, friend operators, localised usings, reduced copy constructors and assignment operators. The clamping types are too complicated for this application. Waypoints once parsed in fact don't need to be, and should not be, stored in memory. Your suggested `operator>>` is going to tank because `getline()` is slow; I'd already tried that.

Comment: Re. heaps - don't actually need to sort at all. `erase_if` was a good lead; the best strategy is to keep a simple vector and blindly perform a linear `erase_if` operation.

Comment: I also like `accumulate`. I'd tried in vain to find a "streamed functional min()" to no avail.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry I don't have time for a thorough review, but I mentioned this in comments:

> ```
>     // std::hypot(dx, dy) makes better use of the library but is much slower
>     double time = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy) / speed;
> ```

I like the comment line - it's a good clear *"why"* that helps us understand the intent here.  We could go a little further and explain why we're sure the faster method won't overflow or underflow (i.e. because `dx` and `dy` are both integers in [-100,100]).

The `sqrt()` function comes from `<cmath>`, which is required to provide `std::sqrt()` and is *permitted but not required* to provide `sqrt()` in the global namespace.  It seems that your C++ environment provides the optional identifier, but relying on that is non-portable, so good code always writes `std::sqrt`, which will work on all conforming platforms.

I believe the [include-what-you-use](https://include-what-you-use.org) tool, also known as `iwyu`, can help resolve transitive include dependencies (such as we have where we expect `<algorithm>` to be included without a standard guarantee).  I'm not aware of any tool to find incorrect use of global-namespace aliases of `std` identifiers.